# Access Denied: You don\'t have permission to access "http://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366/" on this server

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Is there any way to get around this error? I am using splash to grab the HTML, but the response.body returned gives me an access denied. I can view the data in chrome developer tool, but the HTML is unable to be extracted due to this error. Also, when I just use splash, I see the full HTML! I put my github link for anyone:
https://github.com/ryanshrott/scraping/tree/master/demo_airbnb

Access Denied\n\n

## Access Denied

\n \nYou don't have permission to access "http://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366/" on this server.

\nReference #18.66cc94d1.1643648347.66b47664\n\n\n

'

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'simple'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.ca']

    script = '''function main(splash, args)
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))
            return {
                html = splash:html(),
            }
            end'''
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url='https://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366/',
            callback=self.parse,
            args={"lua_source": self.script},
            headers = self.headers
       )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield { 'body' : response.body,
            'title': response.xpath("//h2[@class='_14i3z6h']/text()").get()}
```

Comment: `requests.get("http://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366/")` This works fine to me. Are you sure your additional headers / args are correct?
Also, make sure `airbnb` didn't block you for spamming...

Comment: @AmitSides standard request also works for me. Also, splash in browser works for me. Also httpx works for me. I have no idea what I’m doing wrong on Scrapy side. Are you able to get the Scrapy code to work? This has been a consistent issue for me. For some reason, Scrapy throws all sorts of errors and standard request doesn’t. Baffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a lua script, you need to send the request to the `execute` endpoint as shown in the code below. Also when using `scrapy_splash` be sure to include the required values in the `settings.py` file or the `custom_settings` spider argument as I have done below:

```py
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'simple'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.ca']

    custom_settings = dict(
        SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050',
        DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
        },
        SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
        },
        DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
    )

    script = '''function main(splash, args)
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            assert(splash:wait(0.5))
            return splash:html()
            end'''
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url='https://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366/',
            callback=self.parse,
            args={"lua_source": self.script},
            endpoint='execute',
            headers = self.headers
       )

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.xpath("//*[@id='data-deferred-state']/text()").get()
        yield json.loads(data)
```

If you run the spider using `scrapy crawl simple` or `scrapy runspider simple.py`, you get below output

[image: Sample spider run]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Splash does not seem to get the full HTML of the webpage. However, if I use requests_html.HTMLSession().get(f"https://www.airbnb.ca/rooms/48058366").html.render(sleep=5, timeout=8)  I get the true HTML of the webpage shown in chrome. Why does splash struggle to handle this?

Comment: Is your splash instance running?

Comment: yes it is running properly

Comment: Please share a link to the logs generated by splash

Comment: Here is what I see in splash. The page does not render properly! https://github.com/ryanshrott/scraping/blob/master/abnb/splash.PNG

Comment: From your settings.py file it looks like you are enabling a couple of other middleware like scrapy cloud flare. I haven’t used them before so I don’t know how they affect the request. Probably try disabling everything else and just running with scrapy splash alone. Alternatively take the code I have above save it as a python file and run using `scrapy runspider filename.py` and see if you get a similar response to me.

Comment: I do get a similar response. What did you get for the 'title' output on your end? it's cut off in your screenshot. I get None. Note that using requests, I get the correct title with that xpath expression. I claim that the HTML response you got from splash is incomplete.

Comment: That class is dynamic you should not use it to select the title element coz it changes from request to request. The html is complete

Comment: I guess I don't understand the point of splash then. How do I get splash to return the same HTML as the standard requests library?

Comment: I have examined the response and the data is actually hidden in a json object. I have edited the answer to return the json object containing the data. You can then examine the json object and extract all information about the property.

Comment: ah, how did you know it was there? Any tool or just a search?

Comment: @menior It's still not what I see in chrome and I'm still not able to extract certain things unfortunately :( for example //div[@class='_ytfarf']//td//div//@data-testid does not work, but works in chrome.